# How to form hash from the contents of the following file?

Tags: perl

I have not used hash before but I have a two files as shown below . How to put its contents into hash in such a way that `PIO_M_U_PIO55_1 ,PIO_M_U_PIO55_2` etc becomes the keys and `896, 895` as its values so that its easy to access it in other files . Similarly for second file `UART_10,UART_13` etc become the key and `PIO_M_U_PIO55_1` etc as its value so that i can access `896` directly by `UART_10`. any other way is also welcomed...

```
 #define PIO_M_U_PIO55_1          896
 #define PIO_M_U_PIO55_2          895
 #define PIO_M_U_PIO57_3          894
 #define PIO_M_U_PIO55_4          893
 and so on.....huge file
 Similarly one more file 
  #define UART_10       PIO_M_U_PIO55_1
  #define UART_13       PIO_M_U_PIO55_2
  #define UART_11       PIO_M_U_PIO57_3
   and so on ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two things you're trying to do. Parse a file, and insert into a hash. At a basic level, it goes like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %defines;

open ( my $input_fh, "<", "input-file-name" ) or die $!;
while ( <$input_fh> ) {
    my ( $key, $value ) = ( m/^\s*#\s*define\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/  );
    $defines{$key} = $value;
}

print Dumper \%defines;
```

That's all there is to it, really. A hash is an (unordered) set of key-value pairs.

Comment: That regex could use some refinement: `m/^\s*#\s*define\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/` (although it still doesn't quite follow the C preprocessor's specs)

Comment: Ok, updated. Was aiming more to illustrate the concept, but it's probably good to have a more complete pattern.

Comment: @sobrique creating hash seems to be easy now :) ..its working thanks ....one thing I'v to ask . (\w+) here represent the key and second (\w+) represent the value?? so they are identified by ()?

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash;

while (<>) {
    my ( $key, $value ) = /^\s*#\s*define\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/;
    $hash{$key} = $value;
}

# substitute each value by other value if there is some present
# support transitivity
for my $value ( values %hash ) {
    $value = $hash{$value} while exists $hash{$value};
}

# print out hash content as definitions with final values
print "#define $_ $hash{$_}\n" for sort keys %hash;
```

If you are suspicious there can be a cycle, you can write very simple cycle detection;

```
for my $value ( values %hash ) {
    my %seen;    # cycle detection, stop when $value content is seen twice
    $value = $hash{$value} while exists $hash{$value} and not $seen{$value}++;
}
```

Comment: I suspect someone is on a crusade to downvote people who answered a question they deem too lazy. (So +1 offered in the spirit of balance - I answered too, because I feel that this is a newbie looking for something basic, rather than a 'please do my work for me' post)