# How to create a single hash from two hashes in which values of one hash are subset of keys of another?

Tags: perl

I have created a %hash_1

```
      'PIOMUX2_UART_10' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO1_0'
      'PIOMUX_UART_11' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO0_4'
      'PIOMUX_UART_2' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO23_3'
      'PIOMUX_UART_0' => 'PIO_M_U_PIO21_0'
```

and another %hash_2

```
    'PIO_M_U_PIO1_0'  =>  244
    'PIO_M_U_PIO0_4'  =>  567
    'PIO_M_U_PIO23_3'  =>  568
    'PIO_M_U_PIO21_0'  =>  748
    'PIO_M_U_PIO23_3'  =>  099
    'PIO_M_U_PIO23_3',  =>  887
```

the values of keys in `hash_1` are subset of keys in `hash_2` . I just want to know is there any way I can point the keys of `hash_1` directly to values of `hash_2` and create another `hash_3` which can have keys of `hash_1` and corresponding matching values from `hash_2`.

Comment: You will generally get better answers if you show some attempt at solving the problem yourself, and indicate where you're having problems.

Comment: @Sobrique ok thanks I'll keep that in mind in future ! In most of my previous questions I had given my own code also that i tried and you had also corrected me line by line..very grateful for that :) but I am a little new to hashes but yes for sure I'll keep that in mind :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to form hash from the contents of the following file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093624/how-to-form-hash-from-the-contents-of-the-following-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. All you need is a couple of hash slices. (But note that your `%hash_2` really has only four elements, as three of your keys are identical.)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash_1 = (
  PIOMUX2_UART_10 => "PIO_M_U_PIO1_0",
  PIOMUX_UART_0   => "PIO_M_U_PIO21_0",
  PIOMUX_UART_11  => "PIO_M_U_PIO0_4",
  PIOMUX_UART_2   => "PIO_M_U_PIO23_3",
);

my %hash_2 = (
  PIO_M_U_PIO1_0  =>  244,
  PIO_M_U_PIO0_4  =>  567,
  PIO_M_U_PIO23_3 =>  568,
  PIO_M_U_PIO21_0 =>  748,
  PIO_M_U_PIO23_3 =>  '099',
  PIO_M_U_PIO23_3 =>  887,
);

my %hash_3;
@hash_3{keys %hash_1} = @hash_2{values %hash_1};

use Data::Dump;
dd \%hash_3;
```

**output**

```
{
  PIOMUX2_UART_10 => 244,
  PIOMUX_UART_0   => 748,
  PIOMUX_UART_11  => 567,
  PIOMUX_UART_2   => 887,
}
```

Comment: okay got it ! this answer even helped me to get that hash of array concept..@hash(@array)...just read about it..thankyou soo mch :)

Comment: @Grace90: It's not a *hash of arrays* — that's something else altogether! — it's a *hash slice*, and it's quite simple really. You just use more than one key between the braces and, because it's a multi-valued result, you need an `@` at the beginning instead of a `$`.

Comment: oh okay its returning multiple values so @ got it !!

Comment: Also my hash_1 comes from a diffrent perl script so what I am trying to do is just using open my $handle,'<','file1.pl'; above the code you suggested . file1.pl is the script where I've declared it as our %hash_1 but it still is giving error for not declaring %hash_1.

Comment: @Grace90  You should open a new question for this. `open my $handle, '<', 'file1.pl'` will open the file so that you can read the *source* through `$handle`. How is the hash defined in `file1.pl`? Is it a program that prints it, or is it just a hash definition with no code?

Comment: It is a file which has the program that prints it .

Comment: It sounds like you need `eval`, but please start a new question and show `file1.pl`

Answer (score 1):

First find values of `%hash_1` which are keys in `%hash_2` and then do the mapping of `%hash_1` keys to `%hash_2` values,

```
my %hash_3 = map { $_ =>  $hash_2{$hash_1{$_}} } 
  grep { exists $hash_2{$hash_1{$_}} }
  keys %hash_1;

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash_3;
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'PIOMUX_UART_0' => 748,
      'PIOMUX_UART_11' => 567,
      'PIOMUX2_UART_10' => 244,
      'PIOMUX_UART_2' => 887
    };
```

Comment: @Grace90 your second hash is not valid, as it can't have multiple identical keys..

Comment: Thankyou  understood :) Just one thing actually my hash_1 comes from a diffrent perl script so what I am trying to do is just using                               open my $handle,'<','file1.pl'; above the code you suggested . file1.pl is the script where I've declared it as our %hash_1 but it still is giving error for not declaring %hash_1.

Comment: If you are doing `open my $handle,'<','file1.pl';` you most probably missing something important.